# The usage "Without Which"

Tags: word-usage, word-order

I don't know grammer and english very well.
I want to know whether it is correct or not.

I am trying to mean this:

> These inventions would be impoosible without necessary equipments from
>   Peter, Joseph and Marry. I am grateful to them.

Instead, if I write this:

> I am very grateful to Peter, Joseph, and Mary for necessary equipments
>   without which these inventions would be impossible.

Will it be correct in using "without which"?

Comment: It seems redundant to use "necessary" and "without which ... impossible" to describe the same thing(s).

Comment: Thanks, let's assume the sentence is without "necessary" because my focus is on the usage "without which". Meaningful in the same way or not? Correct or incorrect? I don't know because I am not xx-english. (american english, british english, xx-enlgish) @Davo

Comment: I am very grateful to Peter, Joseph, and Mary for their equipment, without which these inventions would be impossible.  - this is in good form and easily understood.

Comment: So it is the answer. Thank you very much,  @Davo

Comment: Yet another useful question closed for no particular reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second quote, when corrected, is in good form and easily understood:

> I am very grateful to Peter, Joseph, and Mary for their equipment, without which these inventions would be impossible.

Comment: Agreed.  I am quite fond of "without which .. would not be possible."